# How to combine different conditionals in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

this is my reproducible example:

```
SMTscenes.ACC SMTscenes.RESP TrialType 
0             4              Old
0             3              Old
0             r              New
0             2              New
0             1              New
0             r              Old
0             3              Old
0             4              New
```

I started by using the following command to get rid of the "r" so that the next conditionals abide by numbers, then applying the conditional:

```
levels(df$SMTscenes.RESP)[levels(df$SMTscenes.RESP)=="r"] <- "5"
df$SMTscenes.ACC <- ifelse(df$SMTscenes.RESP >= '3' & df$TrialType == 'Old', '1', '0')
df[is.na(df)] <- 1
levels(df$SMTscenes.RESP)[levels(df$SMTscenes.RESP)=="5"] <- "r"
```

This yields

```
SMTscenes.ACC SMTscenes.RESP TrialType 
1             4              Old
1             3              Old
0             r              New
0             2              New
0             1              New
1             r              Old
1             3              Old
0             4              New
```

Here comes the tricky part: If I try to use the following (For 'New' now):

```
levels(df$SMTscenes.RESP)[levels(df$SMTscenes.RESP)=="r"] <- "5"
df$SMTscenes.ACC <- ifelse(df$SMTscenes.RESP <= '2' & df$TrialType == 'New', '1', '0')
df[is.na(df)] <- 1
levels(df$SMTscenes.RESP)[levels(df$SMTscenes.RESP)=="5"] <- "r"
```

then what happens is it reverses the previous step, obviously. Now, I've tried tweaking it in various ways, like mixing the conditionals, all to no avail. What I want the end result to be is this:

```
 SMTscenes.ACC SMTscenes.RESP TrialType 
1             4              Old
1             3              Old
0             r              New
1             2              New
1             1              New
1             r              Old
1             3              Old
0             4              New
```

So, any pointers on how to achieve this? I'd do it manually but there are thousands of rows of data... All help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain in words what are you trying to do?

Comment: Certainly. I'm trying to write a script with conditionals that achieve the following –er– conditions:


If the middle column (SMTscenes.RESP) is 3,4, or r,  and it is Old, then make SMTscenes.ACC = 1; if middle column is 1 or 2, and it is New, then make SMTscenes.ACC = 1. 
Else, make it 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create each index separately then combine with the OR operator (`indx1 | indx2`). And instead of changing the `'r'` values to `'5'` then back and forth, add it as an additional condition:

```
indx1 <- as.numeric(df$SMTscenes.RESP) <= 2 & df$TrialType == "New" 
indx2 <- (as.numeric(df$SMTscenes.RESP) >= 3 | df$SMTscenes.RESP == 'r') & df$TrialType == "Old"
df$SMTscenes.ACC <- as.integer(indx1 | indx2)
df
#   SMTscenes.ACC SMTscenes.RESP TrialType
# 1             1              4       Old
# 2             1              3       Old
# 3             0              r       New
# 4             1              2       New
# 5             1              1       New
# 6             1              r       Old
# 7             1              3       Old
# 8             0              4       New
```

Comment: This is most definitely what I was looking for. Many thanks!